# how to fix an pyodbc operational error while connecting with test server, but working fine with local server

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, langchain

```
import pyodbc 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    driver='{SQL Server}',
    host='####',
    database='HR_Git',
    user='sa',
    password='####'
) 
print(cnxn)  
cursor = cnxn.cursor() 
cursor.execute('Select * from EGV_emp_departments')
for row in cursor:
    print('row = %r' %(row,))
```

> when working with above code I'm able to connect to the test server , but when I'm using

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

server = '####'
database = 'HR_Git'
username = 'sa'
password = '####'  # Removed the space

connection_string = f'mssql+pyodbc://{username}:{password}@{server}:1433/{database}?              driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'

engine = create_engine(connection_string)

result = engine.execute('SELECT * FROM employee')  

for row in result:
    print(row)

engine.dispose()
```

> i'm getting "OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].  (53) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (53)')" error

Comment: there may be multiple reasons such as user doesn;t exists on test, firewal settings, port access etc.